# Why install docker on ubuntu should be `sudo apt-get install docker.io`?

Tags: docker

I think this is better:

```
sudo apt-get install docker
```

But why didn't choose a clearly name?

Comment: docker already exists, and has nothing in common with docker.io/lxc/containers

Comment: For reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce

Answer (score 51, accepted):

http://blog.docker.com/2014/04/docker-in-ubuntu-ubuntu-in-docker/

> Why do Ubuntu use docker-engine as executable name instead of just docker?
> Tutorials, blog posts all now have to mention this difference, “if you use Ubuntu 14.04, or if you are with rest of the world (including earlier versions of Ubuntu)”. Why?
>
> This is because of a Debian/Ubuntu policy; there is already a program called “docker” [1], and it was not allowed to use the same binary name.

Full installation instructions for the most-recent version are at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/.

Comment: And more recently, the package name may have changed again to "docker-engine" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031416/

Comment: I've edited @Thilo's comment to match, since I just shot myself in the foot by not reading the comments.

Comment: So...  all dummy must to uninstall the "opportunistdocker", do `apt purge docker`

Answer (score 3):

issue this to install docker on ubuntu for your development boxes

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh -y
```

if you want very latest dev release then issue

```
curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com/ | sh
```

when running either of above you will notice this walks through the same steps as listed in canonical docker install doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/  which is very handy when installing docker on remote servers and should be used for production boxes

Comment: According to notes at docs.docker.com these scripts are only recommended for developments environments.