# docker current not installed - bash on ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker

I've installed docker on bash on ubuntu on windows 10:

`sudo apt-get install -y docker`

but when i try to use it:

`docker -v`

it gives me the following error:

```
The program 'docker' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install docker
```

When I try to reinstall it, I get this message:

`docker is already the newest version.`

UPDATE:

It seems that one of the pre-requisites for installing docker this way: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ which works on my dedicated ubuntu machine is:

`your kernel must be 3.10 at minimum`

Whereas ubuntu on win 10 is `3.4`

Is there a way to update this?

Comment: what ubuntu is it ?

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get install -y docker-engine`

Comment: @MayurNagekar its ubuntu 14.04 running on win 10

Comment: Looks like you had to install lxc-docker on this version. Try installing docker by following the official page https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Comment: You may need to upgrade to 15.04 or 16.04 for kernel upgrade.

Comment: Try this thread instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379381/docker-command-not-found-even-though-installed-with-apt-get

Answer (score -1):

Run it as root :

```
sudo docker -v
```

Comment: apt-get -y install docker.io   ---> source : https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/