# What is the difference of docker and docker.io in ubuntu apt repository?

Tags: docker, docker-container

What is the difference between docker and docker.io in ubuntu apt repository ?
I know docker.io means docker daemon. However, does "docker" have any role?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978324/why-install-docker-on-ubuntu-should-be-sudo-apt-get-install-docker-io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978324/why-install-docker-on-ubuntu-should-be-sudo-apt-get-install-docker-io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Ubuntu Packages [search page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=docker&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all): `docker` is a system tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications and `docker.io` is a Linux container runtime

---

I did the following search:

- Ubuntu version: `xenial`
- Term: `docker`

> ### Exact hits
>
> #### Package docker
>
> - xenial (16.04LTS) (x11): System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications [universe]
>
>   1.5-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
>
> ### Other hits
>
> #### Package docker-compose
>
> - xenial (16.04LTS) (admin): Punctual, lightweight development environments using Docker [universe]
>     1.5.2-1: all
>
> #### Package docker-registry
>
> - xenial (16.04LTS) (utils): Docker toolset to pack, ship, store, and deliver content [universe]
>     2.3.0~ds1-1: amd64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
>
> #### Package docker.io
>
> - xenial (16.04LTS) (admin): Linux container runtime [universe]
>     1.10.3-0ubuntu6: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x